# In The Hobbit (Book), what was the layout of the barricade on the Front Gate of the Lonely Mountain?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, dwarves, hobbits, smaug

In the book it has this image:

[image]

In the book, it says that they built a wall of bricks covering it, but it also said that they could climb in and out with ladders and ropes, and sit on top of it. How is this possible? Could you walk me through the layout, because I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 4):

### They didn't brick up the door; they built a wall in front of it.

The wall "covered" the door, meaning it provided cover, or hid the door: you couldn't stand on the other side of the wall and see the door. Presumably the wall was higher than the door it protected.

The wall stood immediately in front of the door, so that you could walk out the door and into a small courtyard. In courtyard (the space between the wall and the door, with the rock walls of the entryway on either side) there was room for ladders, which you could use to get up on top of the wall.

Comment: But on that map, it looks as if the river just falls away right after the water leaves the door, which means that there wouldn't be room for a courtyard, or a wall. It looks like its a straight ledge?

Comment: @dreamwithinadream We're talking about a highly stylised illustration of something a great distance away. The courtyard needn't be large--just big enough to squeeze a ladder up from the door to the wall's crown and get a dwarf over the top.